# Query in Ado.net Entity Object Generator template

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I used Ado.net Entity Object Generator template to generate the business objects from the Edmx file. By default it is adding two files namely

1. Model.tt
2. Model.Context.tt

The Model.tt template is generating the business objects, can any one explain the use of Model.Context.tt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model.Context.tt generates your derived context exposing all `ObjectSet`s, function imports etc. You can further extend this context in your own partial class and add custom methods you need. `ObjectContext` is entry point to EF functionality.